# Can't get drawables resolution right for Android tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, resolution, tablet

I use .png as a background for a custom button that I declare in XML like this
android:background="@drawable/samplepng"
But I can't get the resolution right for tablet screens :
For example, my ressource is a 200x200 pixels .png (initially designed for iOS and retina)
I place a 100x100 px version in the drawable-mdpi folder and a 200x200 px version in the drawable-xhdpi folder.
I also need to have a layout for a typical 320x480 screen in the layout folder and another layout for 10" tablets in the layout-xlarge folder.
The size of the button is 100x100 dp in the normal layout and 200x200 dp for xlarge layout, so that it looks right.

With the Android emulator, a 10" tablet uses mdpi ressources and xlarge layout.
As a result, the button background is drawn with a scaled version of the 100x100 image which looks very blurry, as opposed to the crisp 200x200 original image.
If I don't use a mdpi ressource, it looks blurry just as well.

Am I doing something wrong ? is it only an emulator problem and it looks nice on a real device ?
Please help, I read 10 times google's doc but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't launch the emulator with 'Scale display to real size' checked, then it will always use mdpi drawables.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be in the android version your targeting. Try switching the emulator to android 3.0 and 3.1.