# Application Skeleton to support multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

As we know Android coming with various device which having different
Features, Resolution, and Screen-size so while developing an Application which support
multiple (small and big) screen there is an obstacle of size and layout.

This leads to different combinations of *screen sizes, resolutions, and DPIs* and creates quite a challenge when designing and developing for Android devices. While some other Manufacturer (non Android) have different resolutions and DPI, they share the same screen size and the resolutions follow the same aspect ratio. Therefore, an image can be created to fit the non Android devices.

My question is that is there a proper flow or architecture that one should follow to meet the requirement?

[image]

*Remember we do have Tablets of different Size and Resolution.*

I'm aware that [**Android Developer**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) contains this information but my view is from implementation.

From my knowledge what I understood is that for designing Android graphics even Programmer must know the designing concept.

Comment: Are you Guys sure this question isn't constructive?

Comment: I think it is very constructive. Would like to know the reasons of the down votes.

Comment: @MKJParekh take `MicroMax Funbook` http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_funbook_p300-4701.php  `7", 480X800, Ldpi (133 dpi)` can you tell me in which category(drawble-large or Ldpi or if Android v3.0 sw-480) it will fall?

Comment: @LazyNinja the reason of down votes is lunatics and crazy people. Who just think they can only ask constructive questions :p

Comment: @MKJParekh it's been one year, people are still waiting for your super intelligent answer. :p

Comment: @AZ_ :) We used this res structure in res folder

drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-hdpi-v11
drawable-hdpi-v9
drawable-large
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-mdpi-v11
drawable-small
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xhdpi-v11
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi-v11
layout
layout-small
layout-sw530dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-xlarge
values
values-sw530dp
values-sw720dp
values-v14
values-xlarge

and used well defined dimensions in xml from values folder. FYKI our application supports more than 5k types of devices.

Comment: @MKJParekh bro I have also used the same but I didn't use v9. Still haven't got any complaint from customer :) read this very informative http://opensignal.com/reports/2014/android-fragmentation

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Finally created a structure which handle layouts and icon for multiple screen.

Android generalises device displays into categories based on two parameters:

- Screen size, the physical size of the display (measured diagonally)
- Screen density, the physical pixel density of the display (in pixels-per-inch, or ppi)`

To determine screen size & density quickly, please install "[What's my Size](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.qbus.sizemeup&hl=en)" app for Android.

Screen size

Android defines four generalised screen sizes:

---

```
 Qualifier           Size

 small               ~3 inches (approx) 
 normal              ~4 inches (approx) 
 large               Exceeds 4 inches    
 xlarge              Exceeds 7 inches
```

- Most phones are classified as small or normal (roughly 3 to 4 inches diagonally). But now, there are many phones with large screen such as Galaxy S4, HTC One, Xperia Z
- A small tablet like the Samsung Galaxy Tab is classified as large (larger than 4 inches)
- Extra-large applies to large devices, for example large tablets

Android defines four generalised screen densities:

---

```
 Qualifier         Description         Nominal value

 ldpi              low density          120 ppi
 mdpi              medium density       160 ppi
 hdpi              high density         240 ppi
 xhdpi             extra high density   320 ppi
```

Typically:

- screen size has most impact on your app layouts
- screen density has most impact on your image and graphic resources

It is listed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) the percentage difference of device screen

- Ldpi-  75%
- Mdpi-  100% (base according to Android developer site)
- Hdpi-  150%
- XHdpi- 200%

[image]

But as we know now most of device coming with *480X800* so I'm consider this as based device, so our new calculation will like this

- Ldpi-  50%
- Mdpi-  66.67%
- Hdpi-  100%
- XHdpi- 133.33%

which means that first icon and design will be created for *480X800* only and then for rest ones(i.e. Ldpi, Mdpi, Xhdpi).

There are images which are common for all layout and must uniform in color and shape(no complex shape, no curve) so for this kind of image we are creating `9patch` which to be put in “drawable(no-suffix)” folder. To create 9Patch image you can either use [**DrawNinePatch**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) or [**BetterNinePatch**](http://android.elex.pe.kr/a-better-9-patch-tool)

Now just rename your images based on Android's standards and complete your application with `hdpi` and then just take `drawable-hdpi` folder and Open *Adode Photoshop*(recommended)
create [**Action**](http://www.dpandi.com/actions/index.html) of multiple size(just change the size according to percentage ratio) once Action created for all size then just do [**Batch Automate**](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/automate_photoshop_tasks_actions) and give source(drawable-hdpi) and destination(drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xdpi).

The reason I insist you to use Photoshop because it will resize automatically your image with Actions and one more plus point is that you need not to rename the file(it will assign same name as original one).

once you completed with creation of all images, refresh your project and test it.

Sometimes there may be possibility that the layout which support screen(xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi) may be get cut in small screen(ldpi) so for handling this just create separate Layout folder(layout-small) for it and add `ScrollView`(mostly). Thats it.

**Tablet**
Tablets are categorized into two size.

1. 7"(1024X(600-48(navigation bar)))  = 1024X552  (drawable-large)
2. 10"(1280X(800-48(navigation bar))) = 1280X752 (drawable-xlarge)

In this we need to create image for both the screen and just put them accordingly

So all in all we will have this folder in our application to support multiple screen.

```
drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-large
drawable-xlarge
```

*will be more qualifier combination with `Screen size and Screen density`*

```
drawable-large-ldpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-large-xhdpi
```

*more qualifier with `Screen density and Version`*

```
drawable-ldpi-v11
drawable-mdpi-v11
drawable-hdpi-v11
drawable-xhdpi-v11
```

*and more qualifier with `Screen size and Version`*

```
drawable-large-v11
drawable-xlarge-v11
```

*and more qualifier with `Smallest width concept(SW)`*

```
 drawable-sw???dp
```

Further more in Android V3.0 Honeycomb they introduced new concept of `SW(smallest width)` in which device are categorized into screen width, so if we are creating a folder named `drawable-sw360dp` then the device with 720dp(either width or height) will use resource from the this folder.

for example to find the `Samsung Galaxy S3` **dp** to suffix to **drawable-sw?dp**
With reference of [**DP Calculation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms), If you want to support your layout or drawable to S3 then the calculation says

*px= Device's width = 720*
*dpi= Device's density= 320*

formula given

```
    px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

interchanging formula because we have px's value

```
    dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

now putting value,

```
     dp= 720 / (320/160);
     dp=360.
```

so `drawable-sw360dp` will do the job

Get you Device configuaration from [GsmArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/)
Sameway you can also create folder according to Device's Android API version i.e. drawable-hdpi-v11` so the device which is having API11 and it is Hdpi then it will use this resources.

Additional Tips:

- Use relative layouts, dp, sp, and mm

  **dp units** - device independent pixels normalised to 1 physical pixel on a 160 ppi screen i.e. medium density. Scaled at runtime. Use for screen element dimensions

  **sp units** - scaled pixels, specified as floating point values, based on dp units but additionally scaled for the user's font-size preference setting. Scaled at runtime. *Use for font sizes*

  *you should always use RelativeLayout for layouts; AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and should not be used.*
- Use appropriate image formats - PNG versus JPEG

  `Android "prefers" PNG for bitmap image files, "accepts" JPEG, and "discourages" GIF.`

  However, PNG and JPEG are not equivalents. They have different quality trade offs, and PNG is not always best:

  **JPEG** can offer up to 50% file-size reductions over PNG, which is significant if your app is image-intensive

  A higher quality "lossy" JPEG may look better than a highly compressed "lossless" PNG, for the same file size
- Add labels to your images and graphics for debugging
- Use the supports-screens element
- Configure your emulators with real device values

  Conventionally, desktop systems display at 72ppi (Mac), or 96ppi (Windows, Linux). Compared with mobile, desktop displays are always low density.

  Always configure your Android emulators to mimic real device values, and always set them to scale to emulate device density.

  In Eclipse, it's easy to create multiple emulators (from the Eclipse menu bar, select **Window > AVD Manager > New**) configured with values for real devices:

  Name the emulator for the real device it's emulating
  Specify Resolution, don't use Built-in generic sizes
  Set the device density to match the real device (in the Hardware pane set Abstracted LCD Property to the real density, always an integer value)

  When you launch the device, always select Scale display to real size, and type in the real screen dimension in inches.

  If you don't set the device density, the emulator defaults to low density, and always loads ldpi-specific resources. Resolution (pixel dimensions) will be correct, but your density-dependent image resources will not display as intended.

  Of course, nothing you do will reproduce higher density image quality on a lower density desktop display.

Here is the Data collected during a 7-day period ending on October 1, 2012. To see the latest statistic about Android platform version, [go to here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

*Based on Screen Size*

[image]

*Based on Screen Density*

[image]

Comment: For samsung galaxy tab 7" we have to keep images under drawable-large-hdpi otherwise image will get stretched or shrinked.

Comment: @rajpara there are lot of combination and permutation, we will include all such cases later on.

Comment: Then looking for more combimations & permutations.

Comment: uncategorized list: You have Amazon-kindle, Macromax Funbook, Sony Xperia mini etc.

Comment: @hotveryspicy hey, why do my images scale up from a drawable-sw360dp folder? for example i want to support the samsung s3, so my images for example fit a width of 720pixels..but it goes out of propotion :( help

Comment: out of proportion? dint get you can explain in detail or post another question on SO?

Comment: Thanks for sharing of your thoughts with us. But I have been confused by some facts. Don't you see how awkward are the values of scaling factor you get choosing hdpi as a baseline? I even saw a wireframe for application where designer made xhdpi density as a baseline and danced from it, trying to persist quality of images with awkward decimal fractions in scale values of less densities and didn't reach proper results. mdpi is the most convenient baseline to persist image quality, because you got less fault in sizes. And also taking 800x480 hdpi as basic device you just increase this fault.

Comment: see @AlexBonel, ya I do agree with you, but my main motto is to make aware how things can be done when it comes to Multi-screen support. One can modify/manipulate this flow/concept because the above is for making clear the initial problem. Additionally I too do modification based on application design. Your post giving me sense that you understood the concept. Hope you got my point.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html for some more information.

Comment: The above answer is perfect, but just one query:

Can't we use xhdpi image for 10" tablet? 

And you have removed 48 pixels from tablet screen, what for others like hdpi, xhdpi? Do we have to remove navigation bar space also from 480 x 800 size while creating design?

Comment: @MihirShah Yes you can use xhdpi image for 10" tablet for that you need to copy all image to drawable-sw720dp folder. No, As mobile phones(mostly) having hard button for Back, Menu and Home while on Tablet its reside in screen.

Comment: @hotveryspicy: Thanks for your answer. But I was asking for top notification bar space. Its size is around 40 px . So do we have to remove that from (480 x 800). ? Otherwise if we design for 480 x 800, but actual available space is less than 800, so might be our design would not exact that what we expect. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: @MihirShah It will affect, if your application having UI as artistic look and feel but as most of our application having seperate image for background and for every control so except Splash screen, notification area will not affect any. Ya for Splash screen you can show in Full screen mode without notification bar.

Comment: @hotveryspicy: Again thanks for your useful answer. But one last question please. As we design for 480 x 800, and accordingly scales images for others as per ratio (66.66%, 100%, 133%), so for xhdpi according to scale, image size would be: 640 x 1060. But samsung s3 size is 720 x 1280. screen ratio is (1280 / 720) =  1.77, but in our case it would be (1060 / 640) = 1.65. So image might be stretched to fit to screen which affects image's x and y scale. Hope you able understand what I mean. Because there would be some space left at the bottom of the screen in S3 after arranging controls to view.

Comment: @MihirShah yes for S3(720X1280) & S4(1080X1920) resolution you can take image of S4 i.e. 1080X1920 and shrink to 66.67% which now became 720X1280(S3). now calculate S3 & S4 SW dp and create separate folder for both S3 and S4. Furthur also make layout flexible such that it won't change drastically on different device size. Enjoy HD look

Comment: Hi, how can calculate the folder for 2560x1600? for example nexus 10 (300) dp = 2560/(300/160) = values-sw1280dp ?

Comment: Say you want to target French speaking Verizon users in the US that have a screen whose smallest width is 320 dp, their device is in landscape mode and the screen size is larger than 720x060, their touchscreen is intended to be used through direction interaction instead of standard touches, the on-screen keyboard is exposed at the moment but the navigation keys are hidden, and it's the night. You can: `res/drawable-mcc310-mnc-004-fr-sw320dp-xlarge-land-night-finger-keysexposed-navhidden`

Comment: Nice answer. After searching a lot and so many days why this exceptions happening, i got this post as best answer with great example and explanation. e.g. Consider Halo Value 7 inch tablet. PPI=133. Resolution=480*800. Size=7' Inch. If we consider mdpi as base, it should take the dimension defined in values-sw480 but it is taking dimension from values-sw600. Not i got why this is happening. Really thank you so much for your post. Save losts of time and clear the confusion. I think this should be on Android's official site. Appreciate you effort.

Comment: I think this is the best answer I had ever seen. I am looking for such answer since long. And finally I got it . Thanks everyone to contributed for this answer to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Designers should create base designs of

`base size of mdpi devices * density conversion factor of highest supported density bucket`
size.Base screen size is 320 X 480 px and density buckets are as follows:

- ldpi: 0.75
- mdpi: 1.0 (base density)
- hdpi: 1.5
- xhdpi: 2.0
- xxhdpi: 3.0
- xxxhdpi: 4.0

And to tackle extra available space on Android devices should use stretchable components in both the directions (horizontally and vertically). Detailed info is available here:

http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/