# Universal Android application for tablet and mobile

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I want to develop an application which is universal for tablet as well as for mobile. By creating xmls of different screen sizes i.e. small, normal, large, and extra large, does my purpose will be solved?
I am not sure about this, please guide me to develop that application in every aspect.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [designing for multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation.

Beyond that, you may not need layouts for each and every size. Sometimes, scaling a smaller/bigger layout up or down will suffice.

You will also be need to make sure you don't end up using features like cell phone calling, as most tablets don't support that.

Comment: Hi Raghav,
I have gone through the documentation provided by you. The layouts for different sizes need to be provided(mentioned in the document).

Comment: Actually, if you don't provide a layout for a specific size, it defaults to the closest layout provided. So if you have a large layout, but no xlarge, then xlarge devices with use the one from large.