# Android Layout for Different Resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

I wish to create various layouts for various screen resolutions, like `hdpi, xhdpi` etc.

I read up [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about how i can do it.

So i created two directories for `layout-xlarge` and `layout-large` in my `res` directories and placed the `xml` layout there.

My phone that i know to be a `hdpi` phone crashes saying it can not find resource directory.

What am i doing wrong. My phones is `Samsung Nexus s`.

Comment: I am having some hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061

Comment: So does the layout folder work for you?

Comment: i found a solution by using layout-hdpi and layout-xhdpi

Answer (score 1):

For your Samsung Nexus S phone, the `layout` folder will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your manifest :

```
     <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"/>
```