# How to design app for tablet and mobile having different screen sizes

Tags: android

I have problem in Layouts.I am designing app for phone and tablet.In phone I have to use list view and in tablet I have to use  grid view. So please give me solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Layout for Different Resolutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580130/android-layout-for-different-resolutions)

Comment: Please, that's the second post I see from you, and in both, you asked for a solution, it not good way manner.... Try to explain what you do, post your code, explain where you what you want, or wich errors you had... don't just say.."I have a problem, solve it"

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use fragments: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Also, to achieve what you want you should put different layouts in different layout folders like layout-600dp, etc..

For more information please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: requirement is that in phone my phone size is small that's why i use list view in phone and in tablet size is large that's why i use grid view in tablet. please give me solution.

Comment: Just read the last link I've given you, it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just use different layouts with the same ids in every layout
Use list view in one layout and grid view in other and on the basis of their ids use their onclick in your java class.