# How to create device specific layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android application.I created **layout-sw600dp** and **layout-sw720dp** layout folders for tablets 600x1024dp and 720x1280dp along with **layout** folder  for other phones.I am tested these by using samsung galexy tab and emulator of size 720x1280.But it always takes the layout from layout folder.
Why this happen even these layouts are device specific?

How to create a layout specific for tablets.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please note `sw(smallest width)` concept works with Android 3.0 and above.

Comment: I am using android 2.2 google api.How can i create a layout for tablet

Comment: `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge` will help. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Answer (score 0):

when we loading the activity layout using setContentView () , we can do a check the BUILD model and based on that we a give a laod a layout..

Eg:

The code looks somethink simialr to this..

if(android.os.Build.MODEL.equals("XXX"))

setContentView(R.layout.x);

else

setContentView(R.layout.y);

Kindly let me know incase if you need any help.