# Button and background size/resolution in android

Tags: android, android-resolution

I went through the Developer documents,partly understood the LDPI,HDPI,MDPI,XHDPI analogy, searched everywhere on the net but could not find specific answers.

I have two phones, one has a small screen and one is a tablet. I want the buttons on my small screen phone look small and the same buttons on the big screen look more big and occupy more space. How do I achieve this?  Any tutorials?

(I place drawables in specific drawable folders and huge buttons are displayed on my small screen) Confused!

I also created different layouts specifying the DPI, what I dont understand is that if the DPI of my small screen and big screen is same, the layout will be distorted on the bigger or conversly the smaller one!

Comment: a little effort of mine may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: Create different layout resources for different devices say them as layout-small and layout-large/xlarge

Answer (score 2):

apparently you have a lot to learn on the resources as overall, but specifically for buttons you might want to look into using a shape drawables (for simple backgrounds) or 9 patch for more complex ones as those solutions stretch much more efficiently than standard PNG backgrounds.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

google around you'll find good resources on the and even some tools to automate the creation of those resources.

Answer (score 0):

read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and check the size qualifiers section

eg, from the same link

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: And how do you determine the DP? If I have two phones with same dp but one falls in small screen and one falls in large screen!?

Comment: You are wrong `layout-sw600dp` will not going to support 7" tablet with 600dp width and even `layout-sw720dp` will not going to support 10" tablet with 720dp width.

Comment: Eternal confusion in case of layouts Android has!

Comment: @HereticMonk dp is a unit, and is defined as: A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way. What you are confusing with is with screen-density which can by ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdi or other. For example hdpi tablet you can define your layouts in res/layout-hdpi-sw720dp or for mdpi tablet res/layout-mdpi-sw720dp

Comment: Consider I have a tablet 320 dpi and I have a small screen phone 320 dpi. Which implies the button size on both of them will be the same? Even if I design different GUI's for them separately, the spacing will be alright but the size wont!

Comment: keep height and width values for button in values-xhdpi-720dp/dimens.xml and values-xhdpi/dimens.xml for tablet and phone respectively

Comment: Yup, sw selector is the way to go here. Don't take sw600 & sw720 as hard limits : they are very good starting point but the real question is what are the dimensions that your layout need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to go for nine-patch images ?
Here is the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).

It helps you to create nine-patch images instantly .
Here it is some useful information regarding [nine patch.](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)
Just go through it ....
Hope it helps...