# How to load large layouts in Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to load large-layouts in Galaxy S3 which at present is loading layouts by default. Is there anyway to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make folder `layout-sw360dp` and add your all layouts for Galaxy S3 in this folder and check. This will going to work(tested).

For more information check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)