# Where to put bitmaps for Nexus7?

Tags: android

Specs for Nexus7 is 7-inch screen, 1280 x 800 resolution and 216 pixels-per-inch.
I made drawable-xlarge-hdpi folder and put image in that folder.
But when I check bitmap size, I get smaller size than actual size.
What is wrong?
I tried drawable-large-hdpi, but the result is the same.

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image);
int width = image.getWidth(); // this returns smaller than actual size.
```

Comment: I will also go with `drawble-large-hdpi`. Can you just cross check with `sw smallest width` concept, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061

Comment: @hotveryspicy where ever you put images nexus 7 TVDPI(1.33) will auto scale your image. except in res/drawable-tvdpi/my_icon.png   # Bitmap for tv density

Comment: @PadmaKumar thats why I have mentioned to go with `-sw600dp`

Answer (score 0):

This is from a blogpost title: [Getting Your App Ready for Jelly Bean and Nexus 7](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/07/getting-your-app-ready-for-jelly-bean.html)

> As developers we see this as around 600 * 960 density independent
>   pixels and a density of tvdpi.

The post in the same line also asks you not to rush and create new Assets for this density.

This fact is again outlined by [Dianne Hackborn](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts) (she works at Google) here: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8

If you look at the [Google IO 2012 source code](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/), it also suggests (I may have, of course, missed the obvious) that no special assets were created for the Nexus 7 and yet, it looks and works great on it. If you go through both the links, you will find a couple of tips on making sure your `hdpi` Assets will look good on the Nexus 7 too.