# Designing for Extra high resolution Mobiles

Tags: android, resources, screen, resolution

As per android documentation, list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml            
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml 

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png
```

What is the folder name of layouts for extra high resolution mobiles like galaxy note 2.

Comment: You can use SW(Smallest Width) concept ie. `drawable-sw360dp` [for further info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen).

Comment: layout-xlarge and layout-large use other or and u get solution