# images don't adapt to screen type

Tags: android, android-image

I am working on an Android game.

I finally got my app on two devices besides the emulator and realized that even though I have different sized images in the "drawable-hdpi", "...-mdpi", etc folders, they're always the same size. The same goes for my widgets (Buttons, ImageViews).

I was wondering if there's another way to adapt to the different screen sizes? My game is just loading them as Bitmaps when the images are being used and unloading them when they're done.

Also, why aren't my widgets resizing even though I used "dip" in the layout xmls?

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: The whole point of having drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi resources is that they actually appear the same size whatever the density...

Comment: @fiddler, oh now that you say that.. that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you qualify your images with `-hdpi`, `-mdpi`, `-ldpi`, you support different densities.

If you want to distinguish between screen sizes, you must qualify your drawables with `-small`, `-normal`, `-large` and `-xlarge`.

At [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) is an article about this issue, describing screen size, screen density and resolution.

Comment: thanks! that makes more sense now. I'll read that article too. =]