# Designing for different screen - Android

Tags: android, screen

I want my app to run perfectly on different screen sizes, **Galaxy Tab 2**, **Galaxy Note 800** and **Galaxy Note 2**.

However, my app is fairly complex and I can't use `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` at all places. I've tried using `layout_weight` but even that couldn't be used with `RelativeLayout`.

Is there any smart way of resizing your screen components depending upon screen size other than making different layouts all together as suggested in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)  and is there any way to use `layout_weight` in `RelativeLayout`?

Thanks!

Comment: you can refer my efforts and almost working fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: first you design your application for normal layout and make folder in resource folder layout-mdpi ,layout-hdpi etc .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an efficient way round.

Instead of hard coding dimensions in layout I used a reference of them in `Resources/values/dimensions.xml`. So, for different screen sizes I simply made different dimension file in Resources, thereby reducing complexity and avoided making separate layouts for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and in that [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html). I have preferred these to RelativeLayout in one of my project because RelativeLayout does not support weight property as you said.

Comment: My app is fairly complex and TableLayout can't make up for RelativeLayout. Thanks, anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Its true you cannot use weight with Relative Layout. If you want to make sure your layout runs perfectly for every device. You must use Nested LinearLayouts with views and do that in weight your UI will be perfect if you have good resolution images for every device.

Moreover in RelativeLayout complex layout can't be perfect as you cannot use weight and sometimes images may get skew or stretch .

Of course using Nested LinearLayouts with views do increase some extra lines but this is the only perfect solution.

Comment: Using nested layouts uses more resources and increases complexity and isn't an optimized solution. 

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: @ Infinity In the same doc its mentioned Total time taken for nested layout is 3.861ms and Total time taken for simple layout is 2.854 i.e. a difference of merely 1 ms to draw UI, If you cannot comprise with 1 ms then you can never make complex layuots without using weight and nesting.