# How can I fix Image size in Multiple Screens?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

In my project exist 4 drawable folder ,and same image in there

I have splash screen in 4 layout (small,large,xlarge)

[image: splash xlarge]

in xlarge splash layout ,in center I have another image 
but that don't fix with res drawable-xhdpi image same as this

[image: splash screen medium]

```
< merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_logo" />

</ merge>
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: not getting what exactly you asking but to support multiple screen you can do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the sentence between the two images?

Comment: for that I don't use reshape ,I have 4 image in 4 size ,I want to use any image for 4 different size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each drawable folder you haveto store different resoulutions if you want to achieve identical result, or you can use 1 folder and this pic will be resized.

To find out what sizes do you need, check this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your Manifest file :

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"/>
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 9 patch images for differnt screen  to use that image create drawable folder in res and put here your 9 patch images and set this Images in your layout, this may helps you