# Where is that old AVD? What 'Screen' should I select?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

First, you have to consider that I don't have an Android phone, and I am new to Android development.

Please have a look at the attached image.

I used to develop some basic things in android using an AVD different from this. It had buttons as a separate panel. This AVD came after the update of eclipse and re installing android 2.2 .

I got 2 questions.

1. I can't go back after viewing the results of my applications. There are no buttons as well.
2. In eclipse, I can see lot of 'Screens' are provided. Some are Nexus7, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S etc. Previously I didn't use these kind of stuff. Which screen should I use ? Some screens are very small anyway. If I use 'Galaxy Nexus', does that mean that my app is developed only for 'Galaxy' phone? I believe previous Android apps were developed in a way which are suitable for all android devices!

Please help

[image]

Comment: use esc button to go back from the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't go back after viewing the results of my applications. There are no buttons as well.

You can press *Escape* button of your keyboard to go back.

> In eclipse, I can see lot of 'Screens' are provided. Some are Nexus7, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S etc. Previously I didn't use these kind of stuff. Which screen should I use ? Some screens are very small anyway. If I use 'Galaxy Nexus', does that mean that my app is developed only for 'Galaxy' phone? I believe previous Android apps were developed in a way which are suitable for all android devices!

Ya nowadays device are coming with various resolution and size, target(*emulator is for testing*) whatever it may be but you need to create your artwork such a way that it supports all the screen, and to do the same you can see [Application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

Comment: Thanks :). Yes, escape button was the only way!

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, escape button was the only way!

Answer (score 2):

For Going back, you can use escape button. If u are selecting nexus, it doesn't mean that you are developing the application only for nexus 7. If you are selecting nexus, you can view your application as you see in nexus.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like that if you are supporting all screens in your menifest file then your app is for all phones but you have to use different images (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi) and setting some layout dynamically to fir in different screens.

For going back you can press escape button or you can press back button in your emulator.

```
<supports-screens  android:smallScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens  android:normalScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen size you select is for your testing purposes only.  You should test on a wide variety of device sizes and resolutions.  The device you choose when testing is only an example, your application will run on any device that you haven't restricted in the manifest.

I would highly recommend creating a virtual machine for each major device size/resolution you want to target and have a look at how your application behaves on each.

As to your buttons, there's an option when creating these VMs to include external hardware buttons; always turn this on to give yourself buttons to click in the VM.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't go back after viewing the results of my applications. There
> are no buttons as well.

Just change its mode using Left Ctrl + F11, so you will be able to see a back button in your current emulator. As your emulator is not being fit in your screen, the button is being hidden.

> In eclipse, I can see lot of 'Screens' are provided. Some are Nexus7,
> Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S etc. Previously I didn't use these kind of
> stuff. Which screen should I use ? Some screens are very small anyway.
> If I use 'Galaxy Nexus', does that mean that my app is developed only
> for 'Galaxy' phone? I believe previous Android apps were developed in
> a way which are suitable for all android devices!

No, your application will still support all screens as you have specified in manifest file.
If you are comfortable with small size emulators, don't select Nexus while creating emulator. Select other target and device. For example,

> Device: 3.2" QVGA
>
> Target: Android 4.0

Answer (score 1):

[image]

use android virtual device manager and edit your emulator

in that check the Hardware keyboard present checkbox and then restart your emulator