# layout not adjusting to small screen size

Tags: android, layout, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

i am developing an android app. there are different folder created for different size in res folder like layout-large,layout-small,.
 its working fine except small screen size.
 In small screen size its not taking layout from layout-small folder.
   what may be reasons.In small screen size we are considering 240*400.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

For more information  follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html), [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Small screen size refers to the physical dimensions of the screen, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) it must be below 3 to 3.5 inch.

The number of pixels does not really matter (apart from obvious correlations).