# Custom progressbar not fitting properly on screens with different resolution and density

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am stuck with an issue and need some expert suggestions. I have a custom circular progress par whose boundary rotates as an animating light in my splash screen

It looks like this:

[image]

The boundary light continuously rotates till splash screen is there.

Now my splash screen has a background image which has a circle drawing at upper half of image:

It looks like this:

[image]

Now my circular progress bar should fit on that background circle boundary. What ever i do, it fails for some phone screens (circle is misplaced).

How can i fit into background circle and it can work on all phones and tablets.

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

This is how I have defined circular progressbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_splash_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen" /> 


   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progress"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="170dp"
       android:layout_height="170dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"

       android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
       android:visibility="visible"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey can you please add the complete xml code.

Comment: I have added complete xml now.

Comment: Hey if you are using `match_parent` for 1 view and specific value(170 dp) for the other, they will most probably won't fit as you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me resolve the issue to some extent as it now suppots majority of devices. Still I could get a general solution to the problem. But I can consider this as answer:

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `style` attribute and set your `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. The problem is you are setting the style to large which by default has its size pre-defined. Further in your width and height attribute you are trying to resize it. So this might be the problem.

Comment: I tried setting it to match parent but then it does not fit background circle boundary. This code is from one of my layout files for xhdpi screens. I tried to hardcode for different screen resolution but still it misfits for some screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with the `HoloCircular ProgressBar` is a Custom View implementation for Android.

Checkout the [HoloCircular ProgressBar](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar) which might help you.

Other Library that you can use are as below:

1) [Progress Wheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)

2) [ProgressBar](https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c)

3) [Customize the Spinner](http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont think progressbar is my problem. Problem is setting its size so that it fits background circle boundary for all screens.

Comment: Try using the `FrameLayout` in your layout file.