# How to manage the different size of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

To suit different device I need to set different layout. After having reviewed [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support), I didn't find what I want.

It seems that what I need it to set *Aspect ratio* to *long*. But how to manage different size? 1280x720, 1280x768, 1280x800 etc. I create folder `res/layout-480x800`. But eclipse warn me it's a invalid name. Through the article I found what I can only use *Size,Density,Orientation and Aspect ratio*. Could anybody show me how to do it? thx in advance.

Here is a pic to help you understand what I ask. the pieces is 2x2 or 2x1 with a divider.

[image]

Comment: Check this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12258061/1160282

Comment: @SilentKiller Thanks! I make it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your xml's in following folders :

```
layout-hdpi  - for 480x800 (Samsumg Galaxy S2)
layout-large - for Nexus 7"
layout-xlarge - for 10" tablet
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258061/1160282 I solve my problem. I create `res/layout-sw??dp` to fix different size.