# Android targeting medium screen sizes

Tags: android

Relatively new to Android development, so sorry if this is a stupid question(I don't have a full understanding of the layouts yet).

I am trying to optimize my app for medium, high, and x-high dpi devices with a medium screen size.

In Eclipse, I have set up "layout-normal-mdpi", "layout-normal-hdpi" and "layout-normal-xhdpi".

Would this be the most efficient way of deving for my targeted screen size? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using layout folders is the most efficient way to take care of different screen sizes.

The below link will give you complete details. Have a look at it once:

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061)

Comment: One more quick question - will creating more folders inside the resources directory increase the size of the app when someone is downloading it?

Comment: the size of xml files are very small. Infact negligible :). So that wont cause any significant size increment..