# Layout Folder issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, screen-resolution

In my app there are  three layout folder.

```
1)layout(for 480x800 resolution with **hdpi**)
2)layout-large(for 1024x600 resolution with **mdpi**)
3)layout-xlarge(for 1280x800 resolution with **mdpi**)
```

but i have new tablet for `i-ball with resolution (1024x600 -> **hdpi**).`

i don't know how to create design for this tablet.

this i-ball device is take layout file from layout layout(for 480x800 resolution with **hdpi**) folder. but its not looking good design compare with other resolution devices.

Please give me solution for design issue in this device .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create it like layout-large-hdpi...for more details please refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Use Full Link for u http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Earlier you said that you have make three different layout and the resolution of i-ball tablet is 1024x600 -> **hdpi** but by default it takes 480x800 resolution with hdpi... So just go with layout_large with hdpi...

Comment: @khubaib how many folder i have create? and how we know which images is put in above resolution device.designer have created 600x1024,1280x800,480x800 resolution images...then how i know which image is preffer?

Comment: @piyush this device can not take images from layout-large folder.

Comment: @dipali if it can't take it so there is one choice.

Comment: @dipali should go with xhdpi folder for layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37777/discussion-between-dipali-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: @dipali how many folders to create depends on how many different phones you want your app to support. say you are supporting devices not only changes in the resolution and from factor.but devices with different sizes also. then you must have layouts/drawables placed in different folders to support it universally. regarding which image is preferred it is up to you which images you are placing in which drawable folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Samsung Galaxy S3` has same issue..

Here is sample logic of achieve for `Samsung Galaxy S3 device`, you can also try for your device.

for example to find the Samsung Galaxy S3 dp to suffix to drawable-sw?

dp
With reference of [DP Calculation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms), If you want to support your layout or drawable to S3 then the calculation says

px= Device's width = 720
dpi= Device's density= 320

formula given

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

interchanging formula because we have px's value

```
dp = px / (dpi / 160)
```

now putting value,

```
 dp= 720 / (320/160);
 dp=360.
```

so drawable-sw360dp will do the job

[Check this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258061/624069) for more detail.