# android layout for dififferent devices

Tags: android, layout

I have developed a music player application, my problem is the layout design is not unique in all type of device screens. How can I overcome it? I search in web and found some mdpi folders but I cant understand it properly. Please anyone give reference or instruction for above issue

Comment: read this one http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I found to create large, small and normal folders..I want to know from which drawable folders the corresponding layout folders will fetch the image??

Comment: [This blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) can be helpful too. On the question: It depends on the device specification. `large-mdpi` device will use layout from `large` and drawable from `mdpi`, provided if you have `layout-large` and `drawable-mdpi` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the screen resolution and screen density for different screens as these factors govern the layout size.

The below link will give you useful insught:

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061)

Also following links in android developer site is useful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

This concept is very important, so would suggest you to go though all links.