# How to deal with android multi size screen resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout

I made an app , and i am also using layout, layout_large,layout_x large folders for XML.
but when i test my app on 3.7 and 4.7 inch device...they both take XML from normal layout size folder and take layout-large XML for 7 inch tab.
so what should be done for layouts between 3.7 to 5.5 inches??
Help appreciated.

Comment: I believe screen size does not matter, but the PPI (pixels per inch). Although someone should correct me if I am wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to layout folder try using density dependent layout.just as we use for drawables.
eg.hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.

Answer (score 2):

if your min sdk over 13 then try to work with layout-sw600dp... and not with layout-large ..

For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/.

Take a look :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html