# not taking correct dimens folder for 7" and 10" tabs

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet

I have developed an app for phones. Now I need to support it to tablets as well. I need to change few dimensions of few views. I had kept 4 values folders for hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Now for a 7" tab I have kept values-sw600dp and for 10" inch tab I have kept values-sw720dp. But any changes I make in the dimens folders of the 600dp and 720dp does not change when I run in the tab. The 7" tab takes the values of values-hdpi folder. How do I support for both screens and tabs?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 7" inch tap get resourses from sw320dp folder, You need use

> dp = px / (dpi / 160)

to find right size qualifier.

This link have morе information:
[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen/12258061#12258061)

And answer from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=ru#DeclaringTabletLayouts **The proper way to declare tablet layouts was to put them in a directory with the xlarge configuration qualifier (for example, res/layout-xlarge/)**.

Comment: Ok I am using Lenovo pb1-750m. I get 548.57 as the dp value.

Comment: Then sw540-dp - your qualifier, and app will prefer it.

Comment: When I do this, it is affecting my phones. Phones arent taking values-xhdpi amymore.

Comment: I kept 3 folders sw320dp , sw540dp and sw720dp. It is working pretty fine with tabs. But now the phones are getting affected. It takes sw320dp folder dimens. I want to support both tabs and phones

Comment: use for tabs -large-hdpi, -large-xhdpi, -large-xxhdpi

Comment: And documentation say  -xlarge right variant for tabs

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a tablet that has a smallest width of 600dp (values-sw600dp), then it should prioritize that over that over values-hdpi (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)). Are you sure your tablet is actually 600dp?

Comment: I am testing in lenovo pb1-750m which is a 7" tab and has a resolution of 720*1280.