# Android how to choose different dimension problems

Tags: android, dimension

I am new android and i have a question. I am developing a app, and i see this problem. I create layout for Pixel 2 and other devices cant show as Pixel 2. When i research, i learning create layout every dimension.

I added this on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

And created different layout; example login_activity.xml (normal) and login_activity.xml (large). But how choose device this screen, is it automatic or other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/intuit/sdp use this for support layout in multiple screen size.